# Regular Expressions (Regex) 2 expressions: remove spaces before verifying 2nd one

Tags: regex

TLDR:

I have option to add only one regex.

How to make those 2 expressions:

- \s
- (\d{10})(19|20)(\d{2})$:$1$3

work at the same time (one after another) and not separately?

This is not enough: \s|(\d{10})(19|20)(\d{2})$:$1$3

Long description:

I have an expression: '(\d{10})(19|20)(\d{2})$:$1$3'

What it does:

- user password should have 12 digits - ending with last 2 digits of the year
- in case phrase has 14 digits (someone added full year) - ignore digits 11th and 12th

Thanks to that we can accept both codes: 308814310175 and 30881431011975.

Now I'm looking for a way to ignore spaces in case user adds them anywhere by mistake (not my requirement).

Theoretically I can just add '|\s', to get '\s|(\d{10})(19|20)(\d{2})$:$1$3'.

Both regex works separately:

- when someone adds full year - it removes 11th and 12th digits
- when someone adds space - it removes it
  but if someone adds space AND adds full year then only removing of spaces works (because phrase is longer than 14 digits).

So this works:

- 308814310175
- 30881431011975
- 3088143 10119

But this is not working:

- 3088143101 1975

because it removes space OR 11th/12th digits - not making both things work one after another.

How to make both expressions work at the same time?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: "Now I'm looking for a way to ignore spaces in case user adds them anywhere by mistake (not my requirement)." why not remove all the spaces before regexing?

Comment: Can you do it with regex? Regex is the only way I can 'play' with password. I tried to do it with \s (like you said - removing spaces) - but it's not applied first and then the second regex - they work separately.

Comment: You have to use some language to use the regex with so you can use the language's string methods to remove the spaces before hand but if you can't and have to use only regex, then you can first replace `/\s/g` with `''` essentially removing all the spaces.

Comment: I have option to add only ONE regex. So both regex \s and (\d{10})(19|20)(\d{2})$:$1$3 must be somehow combined to work together - where space removal must be applied first. Can you do it with one regex?

Comment: Not sure what you are after exactly, but if you do this the ugly way, just capture all seperate digits. See [this](https://regex101.com/r/Hp7gDU/1) demo.

Comment: This really solves the problem. Thank you very much for this complicated solution - I would never come up with this idea. Can I mark this as a solution somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A somewhat long solution would be to capture any digit seperately and avoid spaces and a possible 11th and 12 digit in case of 14 digits total:

```
^\s*(\d)\s*(\d)\s*(\d)\s*(\d)\s*(\d)\s*(\d)\s*(\d)\s*(\d)\s*(\d)\s*(\d)\s*(?:1\s*9|2\s*0)?\s*(\d)\s*(\d)\s*$
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/Hp7gDU/1). You would then replace this with `$1$2$3$4$5$5$6$7$8$9$10$11$12`

---

Another possibility (if supported) could be to replace:

```
(?:[^\S\n]|(?<=^\s*(?:\d\s*?){10})\s*(?:1\s*9|2\s*0)(?=\s*\d\s*\d\s*$))
```

With nothing. But this would require zero-width lookbehind. See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/srACcM/1)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to solve a simple problem in a complicated way. Instead of using a complicated regex, just use two simple steps:

1. Remove unwanted spaces.
2. Apply the regex to validate the string and remove other unwanted characters.

Comment: I don't have possibility to remove spaces before - I have only one feature in the system where I have possibility to add one regex. Anyways JvdV in other comment already solved it. Thanks for comment!